# What's the big deal about $M_{13}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, groupoids

$M_{13}$ is the **Mathieu groupoid** defined by Conway in

> Conway, J. H. $M_{13}$. Surveys in combinatorics, 1997 (London), 1–11, 
>   London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 241, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 1997.

$M_{13}$ has been studied in various places, most notably (for me) here:

> Conway, John H.; Elkies, Noam D.; Martin, Jeremy L. *The Mathieu group $M_{12}$ and its pseudogroup extension $M_{13}$*. Experiment. Math. 15 (2006), no. 2, 223–236.

The title contains my question, albeit stated a little flippantly. Let me start by stating that I don't want to suggest that $M_{13}$ **isn't** a big deal - in particular, I've spent a deal of time reading the paper by Conway, Elkies and Martin and there is some very cool stuff in it. So...

Descriptions of $M_{13}$ usually start with Conway's anecdote describing the parallel between the structure of $M_{12}$ and the simple group $SL_3(3)$ leading him to wonder if somehow one can extend $M_{12}$ to give a groupoid in a natural way. And this groupoid would be 6-transitive (in some sense of the word). Now $M_{13}$ does the trick.

**Transitivity**: My beef is that one can find any number of copies of $M_{12}$ lying around in $S_{13}$ and, if you take an appropriate set of 13 cosets of $M_{12}$, then you will end up with a groupoid that is (in some sense) 6-transitive. In particular, if you take the product of $M_{12}$ with any transitive subgroup of $S_{13}$ whose stabilizer lies in $M_{12}$, then you will get such a groupoid. Now $M_{13}$ is just the product of $M_{12}$ with (a copy of) $SL_3(3)$, and so there you have it.

I could just as easily do the same with $M_{24}$ and any regular subgroup of $S_{25}$.

**The Game**: Of course $M_{13}$ is defined in a particularly elegant way - via a "game" played on the projective plane of order 3. For me, though, the really amazing thing about this set-up is that the set of *closed moves* gives the group $M_{12}$. The set $M_{13}$ is just a byproduct of this (striking and very intriguing) fact. There are other natural extensions of $M_{12}$ using this game (Some coauthors and I define one such [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1701).)

Having said this, Scott Carnahan answered [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108978/has-any-attempt-been-made-to-classify-finite-groupoids) by stating that this game gives "a representation of $M_{13}$ on a finite state machine" and this is what makes $M_{13}$ remarkable. In some sense Scott's answer explains why $M_{13}$ is a big deal, but it's not quite in the direction I'm looking for...

**Back to transitivity**: What I would like is a *characterization* of $M_{13}$ via some group-theoretic properties. For instance as a subset of a permutation group, via the notion of transitivity: So, for instance, we can characterize $M_{12}$ and $M_{24}$ as the only subgroups of $S_n$ that don't contain $A_n$ and that are 5-transitive. Here's an analogous statement that (if true) would be the sort of thing I'm looking for.

> **A characterization of $M_{13}$?**... $M_{13}$ is the only subset of $S_n$ that is not almost all of $S_n$ and for which at least $\frac{1}{n}$ of the 6-tuples of distinct elements are universal donors, and at least $\frac{1}{n}$ of the 6-tuples of distinct elements are universal recipients.

The notions of *universal donors and recipients* are described in Conway, Elkies, Martin above and pertain to transitivity for groupoids. The notion of *almost all* is hopefully obvious. I'm deliberately leaving the statement rough because it's just a vague musing.

(In particular I'm not even sure that at least $\frac{1}{n}$ of the 6-tuples of distinct elements *really are* universal recipients for $M_{13}$ - but it's certainly some large fraction. Moreover the statement can't be right because supersets of $M_{13}$ are also included... But I hope it gives a rough idea.)

There might be other ways of approaching this, and that's what I'm looking for with this question. To me the key thing should be that the characterization of $M_{13}$ should not just be an immediate consequence of the fact that it contains a copy of $M_{12}$ which is itself a remarkable group. I don't *think* the statement I suggest falls foul of this...

**Added later**: People are suggesting that this question is too vague, so let me sum up as follows:

> $M_{13}$ is a union of cosets of a permutation group. There are many unions of cosets of permutation groups but we don't usually bother studying them. Why do people bother with $M_{13}$?

Comment: Another possible characterization in a slightly different direction: $M_{13}$ is the only 6-transitive groupoid whose non-trivial elements have support at least $\frac13(n-1)$.

Comment: What precisely are you actually asking? -- To me your question seems pretty vague.

Comment: @StefanKohl, roughly speaking, I would like to know if $M_{13}$ can be characterized as a subset of a permutation group in some basic way. Alternatively, I would like some context and motivation explaining (from a group theoretic point of view) the construction of $M_{13}$. Hmmm, perhaps that's still too vague...

Comment: Since 3 people have upvoted Stefan Kohl's comment let me put the question another way, more bluntly: $M_{13}$ is a union of cosets of a permutation group. There are many unions of cosets of permutation groups but we don't usually bother studying them. Why do people bother with $M_{13}$?

Comment: The name of Scott C. was correct, now it is wrong. I do not edit as you seem in the process of doing so.

Comment: @quid, thanks! Was editing in too much haste...

Comment: I am curious about two things (which I admit do not directly relate to your question).  First, what is the status of $M_{13}$ as a sharply $6$-transitive set?  This paper http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1011211907282 claims Conway said it is, but allegedly disproves that it is.  I haven't thought about this carefully.  Second, assuming $M_{13}$ is not sharp, what is its minimum distance as a permutation code (under Hamming distance)?  Stepping in the direction of your question, if the distance is fairly large, is this "code" unique in some sense?

Comment: @PeterDukes, you should look at the Conway-Elkies-Martin paper to see the precise status of $M_{13}$ as a sharply 6-transitive set. (This is where the notions of *universal donor and recipient* come in.) As for the connection to codes... I don't know much about these things in general, so can't answer this but I like the sound of it as a possible way of answering my question.