# Is there a Geometric/Smooth version of Homotopy Hypothesis using the path $\infty$-Groupoid of a Smooth Space?

Tags: higher-category-theory, stacks, infinity-categories, groupoids, infinity-topos-theory

A version of *Homotopy Hypothesis*  says that the Fundamental $n$-grupoids model Homotopy $n$-types... and if we continue upto $\infty$, then the Fundamental $\infty$- groupoids or Kan Complexes model Topological spaces upto Weak Homotopy.

Now in *Higher Gauge Theory* there is a notion of *Path Groupoid* of a smooth space https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+groupoid which is a refinement of fundamental groupoid of a topological space and which **remembers more information**(*Thin homotopy class*) than the fundamental Groupoid (*homotopy class*). Analogous to the notion of *Higher Fundamental Groupoids* of a topological space one can define higher Path Groupoids of a smooth space https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+n-groupoid. Also one can go upto $\infty$ and can analogously define Path $\infty$-Groupoid of a smooth space https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+infinity-groupoid.

**My Questions are the following:**

1. What do Path $\infty$-Groupoid of a smooth space models?
2. Is there an analogous smooth or geometric version of *Homotopy Hypothesis* which deals with Path $\infty$-Groupoid of a smooth space?

Now according to **Remark 4.3** in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/diffeological+space#OnTopologicalHomotopyTypeAndDiffeologicalShape one can present Path $\infty$-Groupoid of a smooth space as a *diffeological singular simplicial set*. Also they mentioned that the *diffeological singular simplicial set* $Sing_{diff}(X)$ of a smooth space $X$ is equivalent to the *"Shape"* of $X$. (Though I could not  understand clearly what they actually meant by *"shape"* of $X$).

Now according to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+infinity-stack#in_terms_of_groupoids_internal_to_smooth_spaces an $\infty$-groupoid internal to *diffeological spaces* models Smooth $\infty$-stack. Now I guess  Path $\infty$-Groupoid of a smooth space is also an $\infty$-groupoid internal to *diffeological spaces*. So I am expecting Path $\infty$-Groupoid to model Smooth $\infty$-stack.

So in that case **I am expecting** **the answer** **to my questions** is:

*Path $\infty$-Groupoid of a smooth space $X$  models Smooth $\infty$-stack over the site $O(X)$ and a geometric/smooth version of *Homotopy Hypothesis* will say that the Path $\infty$-Groupoid of $X$ is same as Smooth $\infty$-stack over $O(X)$  which is same as a diffeological singular simplicial set $Sing_{diff}(X)$*.

But still my answer is  **incomplete** in the sense that I still do not know completely what **extra information** does the Path $\infty$-Groupoid of $X$ captures about the smooth space $X$ other than the homotopical information of the underlying topological space of $X$.

Also I am feeling **little positive**  about my expectations because of the following reason:

Roughly the usual *Homotopy Hypothesis* makes sense because $Top_{Quillen}$ is Quillen Equivalent to $sSets_{Quillen}$ via the total singular complex functor $Sing$ and the geometric realization functor $|-|$. Now according to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+diffeological+spaces I am guessing that we may have different model structures on the category of diffeological spaces(**Diff**). Then for my **claim** of "*Smooth or Geometric Homotopy Hypotheis*" to be more meaningful I should expect a Quillen equivalence of Model categories between **Diff**(with some Model structure) and **sSets**(*with some Model Structure*). Now according to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+diffeological+spaces#details there exists a Quillen equivalence between **Diff**(with some appropriate model structure) and $Top_{Quillen}$.(**Though it is mentioned in the same page that there may exist some gap in the proof of this Quillen Equivalence**). *Now If I assume for the time being that there is no gap in the proof* then in that case we get that **Diff**(*with appropriate Model Structure*) is Quillen equivalent to $sSets_{Quillen}$(because $sSets_{Quillen}$ is Quillen equivalent to $Top_{Quillen}$). **But I am not sure whether this Quillen equivalence is given via $Sing_{diff}$ and $|-|$ or not as mentioned in** https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/diffeological+space#OnTopologicalHomotopyTypeAndDiffeologicalShape.

**If this is not the case then I can't say anything. But if it is the case then this is what I expected.** Even if it is true still this Quillen Equivalence is not a sufficient condition for my claim of *Smooth or Geometric Homotopy Hypotheis*" to hold true  but definitely it can give a **positive feeling** about my claim.

Am I misunderstanding anything? Or are my expectations not making much sense?

I am not an expert, so apology in advance if I sound stupid.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the smooth path $\infty$-groupoid is different from the smooth fundamental $\infty$-groupoid, since the whole point of eg the path 1-groupoid is that associativity is forced on path concatenation by a quotient of the space of all paths. Note also that the page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+infinity-groupoid has only been updated _once_ in the past 11 years, to fix a bug with page rendering, and to remove material that looks, to me at least, a bit dubious. That's not to say one can't ask about a diffeological/Lie $\infty$-groupoid $\Pi_\infty$ and the Homotopy Hypoth

Comment: People do study homotopy types of diffeological spaces, for instance Dan Christensen (see eg https://theoreticalatlas.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/dan-christensen-on-diffeological-spaces-and-homotopy-theory/ and Christensen–Wu _The homotopy theory of diffeological spaces_ https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6394 New York J. Math. 20 (2014), 1269-1303)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you Sir for the comment. But I guess the usual path groupoid is different from smooth fundamental groupoid in the sense that the parallel transport over a Principal $G$ bundle(with non trivial curvature) is not invariant under homotopy but is invariant under Thin homotopy. So from this observation isn't it counter intuitive to believe that smooth fundamental $\infty$ groupoid is same as Path $\infty$ groupoid? (I am not an expert, so apology in advance if I sound stupid).

Comment: @DavidRoberts Also I guess there is already a notion of Principal $\infty$ bundles https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principal+infinity-bundle#smooth_principal_bundles with (an appropriate notion of Smoothness ) with a possibly higher notion of Parallel transport in it . Now taking account of this fact and my previous comment on parallel transport of Classical Principal $G$ bundles isn't it counter intuitive to think that Smooth Fundamental $\infty$ groupoid is same as Path $\infty$ groupoid?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you Sir for the reference on Homotopy types of Diffeological Spaces.

Comment: The page you link to about the path $\infty$-groupoid has no definition, it just mentions an analogy, and then gives no hints as to how it might even work. The definition at the other page linked there is the same as the ordinary fundamental $\infty$-groupoid, just with the induced diffeological structure. The underlying Kan complex is the same, unlike the path 1-groupoid case.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes I agree that the prsentation of Path $\infty$ groupoid as a diffeological singular simplicial set  is same as the usual singular simplicial set (If we talk about only the underlying Kan Complex). So are you saying that the induced diffeological structure is playing no role at all?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Then in that case , from the intuition we developed from Path 1-Groupoid case it seems to me that when we are moving upto to infinity level then we are loosing  a lot of information if we present them as a Diffeological singular simplicial set. So it seems to me that the  presentation of Path $\infty$ groupoid as a diffeological singular simplicial set is not an appropriate one then . So can we expect to find a much suitable presentation in future? Or there are some technical reasons due to which we cannot expect to improve the presentation of Path $\infty$ groupoid ?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but I strongly suggest the 1-groupoid case is too degenerate to get a proper intuition. I will point out that even the underlying algebraic structure of the path 1-groupoid and the fundamental groupoid are completely different, even ignoring the diffeological structures that both naturally carry.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks!! I got your point. I guess you are saying that though Path 1-groupoid of a smooth space is very much different from smooth fundamental 1- groupoid  but if we "move up to infinity" and present them as Kan complexes  then they are becoming same object. Am I right?

Comment: @DavidRoberts We know that both smooth fundamental 1-groupoid $\pi_{\leq 1}$ and path 1-groupoid $\pi'_{\leq 1}$ constructions induce functors from $Man \rightarrow Groupoids$. Now, $ |N \circ \pi_{\leq 1}(X)|$ will tell us everything about the 1st homotopy groups of $X$.(Where $N$ is the nerve). Now if we repeat the same with $\pi'_{\leq 1}(X)$ then should I expect $ |N \circ \pi_{\leq 1}(X)|=  |N \circ \pi'i_{\leq 1}(X)|$ or something different? I got this intuition from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360118/what-is-the-geometric-realization-of-the-the-nerve-of-a-fundamental-groupoid-of

Comment: @DavidRoberts Here $"="$ is in appropriate sense.

Comment: These should be new and separate questions.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I am apologising for repeating the same mistake again.

Comment: @DavidRoberts As you suggested I asked a separate question here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369541/what-is-the-difference-between-path-infty-groupoid-and-smooth-fundamental-i